# Image path reading which is in another package in java

Tags: java, image, path

I have my java class in package **hello**/com/abc/xyz/Test.java

In this **"Test.java"** file I am writing code to generate HTML. In which it contains image tag.something like

```
String str ="<Table><img src=""></img></table>
```

My image is in another package as **hello123**/web/img/myImg.jpg.

How I can access this image in my Test.java file.

if I hard code path like "c://myproject/hello123/web/img/myImg.jpg" its working. But this path will not be consistent in other places and other environments.

I tried putting my image in same folder as my java file...not worked.

Can any body help in this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Class` method `getResource` [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourcejava.lang.String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29)  . This will load relative to your classpath, so as long as the image is on the classpath, you can find it.

Code would look like:

```
getClass().getResource("/path/to/image")
```

to get the image URL (which you can then convert to a file path if needed)

Comment: Thanks Jeff. it worked for 1 image. Also I have another image.first image I did                                                                 URL firstImage= this.getClass().getResource("/myImg.jpg"); firstImage.toString();                                              But if i tried for another image like URL secondImage= this.getClass().getResource("/myImg123.jpg");   its not working.

Comment: Is the second image on your classpath?